# Evaluate $\sum _{n=1}^{k}\frac{{\left(-4\right)}^{n+2}}{(n-2{)}^{2}}\prod _{i=n}^{2k}\frac{i}{i+1}$ for $k=3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation, products, sequence-of-function

$\sum _{n=1}^{k}\frac{{\left(-4\right)}^{n+2}}{(n-2{)}^{2}}\prod _{i=n}^{2k}\frac{i}{i+1}$

How can I think this for k=3 ?

**Here is my idea:** $\prod _{i=n}^{6}\frac{i}{i+1}=\frac{1}{2}.\frac{3}{4}.\frac{4}{5}.\frac{5}{6}.\frac{6}{7}$

then

$\frac{3}{14}\sum _{n=1}^{3}\frac{{\left(-4\right)}^{n+2}}{{\left(n-2\right)}^{2}}=\frac{3}{14}.\left(\frac{{\left(-4\right)}^{3}}{{\left(1-2\right)}^{2}}+\frac{{\left(-4\right)}^{5}}{{\left(3-2\right)}^{2}}\right)=-233,1428571$

Is my idea correct?

Comment: How do you handle the case where $n=2$ ?

Answer (score 1):

*Note: * For $k=1$ to $3$ we have to evaulate the sum for $k\in\{1,2,3\}$:
\begin{align*}
\sum _{n=1}^{k}\frac{{\left(-4\right)}^{n+2}}{(n-2{)}^{2}}\prod _{i=n}^{2k}\frac{i}{i+1}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
**Hint:** Evaluation at $n=2$ is not feasible, since in that case we have division by zero, which is not admissible. In order to overcome this problem we can *exclude* the value which causes the indeterminate expressions;.

> We consider the  valid expression:
> \begin{align*}
> \sum _{{n=1}\atop{n\ne 2}}^{k}\frac{{\left(-4\right)}^{n+2}}{(n-2{)}^{2}}
> \prod _{i=n}^{2k}\frac{i}{i+1}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
> which  can be simplified, since
> \begin{align*}
> \prod _{i=n}^{2k}\frac{i}{i+1}&=\frac{n}{n+1}\cdot\frac{n+1}{n+2}\cdots\frac{2k}{2k+1 }\\
> &=\frac{n}{2k+2}
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

That's a telescoping product so

$\begin{array}\\
\sum _{n=1}^{k}\dfrac{{\left(-4\right)}^{n+2}}{(n-2{)}^{2}}\prod _{i=n}^{2k}\dfrac{i}{i+1}
&=\sum _{n=1}^{k}\dfrac{{\left(-4\right)}^{n+2}}{(n-2{)}^{2}}\dfrac{n}{2k+1}\\
\end{array}
$

but then there is a problem at $n=2$
when there is a division by zero.

I'll change that to $n+2$
and we get

$\begin{array}\\
\sum _{n=1}^{k}\dfrac{{\left(-4\right)}^{n+2}}{(n+2{)}^{2}}\prod _{i=n}^{2k}\dfrac{i}{i+1}
&=\sum _{n=1}^{k}\dfrac{{\left(-4\right)}^{n+2}}{(n+2{)}^{2}}\dfrac{n}{2k+1}\\
&=\dfrac1{2k+1}\sum _{n=3}^{k+2}\dfrac{{\left(-4\right)}^{n}(n-2)}{n^2}\\
&=\dfrac1{2k+1}\sum _{n=3}^{k+2}\dfrac{{\left(-4\right)}^{n}n}{n^2}-\dfrac1{2k+1}\sum _{n=3}^{k+2}\dfrac{{\left(-4\right)}^{n}2}{n^2}\\
&=\dfrac1{2k+1}\sum _{n=3}^{k+2}\dfrac{{\left(-4\right)}^{n}}{n}-\dfrac{2}{2k+1}\sum _{n=3}^{k+2}\dfrac{{\left(-4\right)}^{n}}{n^2}\\
\end{array}
$

and these can be handeled
by the usual methods.

Comment: you can not change the question, this is correct question but we think that n does not equal to 2

Comment: The telescoping product comment still holds. Use that.